# Unable to configure mobx in monorepo (using yarn workspaces)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I am trying to setup a monorepo with react and react native app using a yarn workspaces.

My problem is with mobx (and react-mobx) library. When I use it in the shared package it does not work.

Here is the simple component in the shared library. It should just render a button and number and increment the number when the text is clicked:

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react'
import {action, decorate, computed, observable} from 'mobx'
import {observer} from 'mobx-react'

class Store {
    _number = 0

    increment = () => {
        this._number++
    }

    get number() {
        return String(this._number)
    }
}

// All of those are defined
console.log('TEST', {action, decorate, computed, observable, observer})

decorate(Store, {
    _number: observable,
    increment: action,
    number: computed,
})

class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        clickableComponent: 'button',
        numberElement: 'div',
    }

    store = new Store()

    render() {
        const {clickableComponent: ClickableComponent, numberElement: NumberElement} = this.props
        const {number, increment} = this.store

        return <Fragment>
            <ClickableComponent onClick={increment}>Incremenet</ClickableComponent>
            <NumberElement>{number}</NumberElement>
        </Fragment>
    }
}

export default observer(TestComponent)
```

In browser (react) app I get the following error:

```
Failed to compile

PATH_TO_PROJECT]/monorepo-rn/node_modules/mobx-react/index.module.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in '[PATH_TO_PROJECT]/monorepo-rn/node_modules/mobx-react'
```

In native app (react-native) I get the following runtime error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native` from `PATH_TO_PROJECT]/monorepo-rn/node_modules/mobx-react/native.js`: Module `react-native` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

I think the problem is with packages and linking them. There are couple of things I've tried to fix this issue, none of them worked:

- Add `mobx` and `mobx-react` into `workspaces.nohoist`
- Move all dependencies of the shared library into `peerDependencies`
- Make sure to use `mobx@4.x` so it is compatible with react-native

Here is the root package.json:

```
{
  "name": "monorepo-rn",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/**"
    ],
    "nohoist": [
      "**/react-native",
      "**/react-native/**"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "run:web": "yarn workspace web start",
    "run:native:ios": "yarn workspace nativeapp react-native run-ios",
    "run:native:android": "yarn workspace nativeapp react-native run-android"
  }
}
```

Here is the package.json of the shared package:

```
{
  "name": "test-component",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --out-dir lib"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "mobx": "^4.x",
    "mobx-react": "^5.x",
    "react": "^16.x",
    "react-dom": "^16.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "mobx": "^4.9.2",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Here is the package.json of the webapp:

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "mobx": "^4.9.2",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "test-component": "1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-app-rewire-babel-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

And here is the package.json of the react-native app:

```
{
  "name": "nativeapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "test-component": "1.0.0",
    "mobx": "^4.9.2",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.0.0",
    "jest": "24.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I am using the latest yarn version to date: 1.13.0

I've created a repo with which it is possible to replicate the issue I have [here](https://github.com/kaladivo/react-monorepo-mobx-issue).

If anyone will be able to help me get it working I will be insanely grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. I needed to add `mobx-react` into `nohoist` of the root `package.json` file (see the snippet bellow). I had to tweak the native configuration lite bit (I've used [react-native-monorepo-helper](https://github.com/flisboac/react-native-monorepo-helper)). The app now works on all platforms as it should.

The fix was to add following nohoist into the root `package.json`:

```
"nohoist": [
      "**/react-native",
      "**/react-native/**",
      "**/mobx-react/**",
      "**/mobx-react"
    ]
```

See [this repo](https://github.com/kaladivo/react-monorepo-mobx-issue). It now contains working code.

Comment: What I want to understand is: why?

Comment: @Marc Say you have `repo-root/my-project/node_modules/react-native and `repo-root/my-project/node_modules/mobx-react`. Then you do something that causes `mobx-react` to be hoisted to `repo-root/node_modules/mobx-react`. Then, when `mobx-react` tries to import `react-native`, `react-native` can't be found, because `react-native` is not in any `node_modules` directory visible to `mobx-react`. `nohoist` ensures `mobx-react` is not hoisted, so the problem never happens.